# How can I share the same instance to all derived classes in multiple threads with C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am using **command pattern** in C#.
There is a class that contains some properties named `RequiredData`.

```
public class RequiredData
{
  public Class1 class1 { get; set; }
  public int value1 {get; set;}
}
```

There is an abstract class `BaseCommand` and there are some derived classes like `command1 , command2 etc`.

```
   abstract class BaseCommand : ICommand { }
```

The commands operate some actions like:

```
command1.Execute();
command2.Execute();
```

I want during the whole process to have a shared **RequiredData** object which can be updated and used from all commands.
For example:

in command1 Execute method to access the value1 like :

```
RequiredData.Value1 = 5
```

and then in command2 Execute method to have this value like

```
    var k = RequiredData.Value1 //and be 5..
or RequiredData.Class1.something = "something"
```

I tried this one in the base class:

```
  abstract class BaseCommand : ICommand
  {
      //or protected and not private...
      public static RequiredData RequiredData = new RequiredData();
   }
```

is this thread-safe?

What changes needed here for a thread-safe solution?

Comment: It _seems_ like `static` is the right choice - but it will be used by all instances of all derived classes, so it's not clear if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Consider using dependency injection & IoC, which is generally a _much_ better approach.

Comment: @DStanley yes I want to use the object in all instances and also to be able to change object properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by using several methods.

- Pass the shared instance into the constructor
- Singleton pattern/static could help, but is more restricted.

Reminder is, if you use the class on different thread, you need to care about thread safety.

---

Normally I avoid a static object that can be readed/writed by multiple threads. I advise you to try to get rid from this.

But... you need to be sure, that the object/reference types are not accessible from the outside.

like:

```
// you could create the locking in this class, but the class1 property is a
// reference type, so just locking in the property is not enought, it
// goes wrong when the Class1 has properties itself. (then these will be
// altered outside the lock..
// I choose to wrap the whole object and only returning value types

public class RequiredData
{
    public Class1 class1 { get; set; }
    public int value1 {get; set;}
}

abstract class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    // protected.. should not be accessable from the outside..!
    protected static RequiredData RequiredData = new RequiredData();

    public int GetValue()
    {
        lock(RequiredData)
            return RequiredData.value1;
    }

    public void SetValue(int value)
    {
        lock(RequiredData)
            RequiredData.value1 = value;
    }

// or you could wrap this in a property

    public int Value
    {
        get { return lock(RequiredData) RequiredData.value1; }
        set { lock(RequiredData) RequiredData.value1 = value; }
    }


    public string GetSomething()
    {
        // try to avoid returning reference types, but the can be referenced from outside the object.
        lock(RequiredData)
            return RequiredData.Class1.something;
    }
}
```

So the locking should be inside the `BaseCommand`. And the `BaseCommand` should be responsible for communicating with the RequiredData. *(so no other object could have a reference to the RequiredData)*

Like I said: Multithreading / static read/writer = playing with fire.

---

If you have many readers/writers you should have a look at the ReaderWriterLock(Slim). Because multiple threads can read simultaneously and only one writer is active.

Comment: nice approach because I am using different thread.Can you provide a code example?thanks

Comment: I think the static pattern like you showed, is ok. You need some locking in the `RequiredData` per property.

Comment: can you help me more about the locking and where can I put it?

Comment: I also changed the title because it is important.

Comment: now the question is what if I have the Required data with many properties and classes inside? Do I have to use lock for every property I am working with?And the other one is what if I have only to read some properties that was instantiated one time and wont be changed? Can you provide an alternative with singleton?

Comment: You should have a lock when reading a value from the `RequiredData` no matter if it is a property of a property. But I showed if you want to return a value, you need the full path in a lock

Comment: So if I simply pass the whole command to the new thread, the RequiredData will be available? And how about performance issues?